# pass parameter from jsp to servlet hidden

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> This is my code in choose.jsp

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills  nav-stacked ">
<li>
<form action="persom" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<%= request.getParameter("eno") %>">
<input type="submit" value="PC">
</form> 
</li>
<li>Printer</li> 
<li>Scanner</li>
</ul
```

> This is the code in servlet

```
String employee_num = request.getParameter("hidden") ;
PrintWriter pw= response.getWriter();
pw.println("<h2> " + employee_num + "</h2>");
```

It is returning null as output. The value I'm passsing is from servlet through which i invoked the choose.jsp, please help.

Comment: Can you show where you call `choose.jsp` and passing the param `hidden`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think parameter from servlet may be coming as Null . Do one thing receive parameter in a variable some where else on the jsp page , and print it . Check if it is coming null from servlet side only or not . And if it is not null, just pass variable in the value field as, let's say <%=empNo%> .Let me know if that works :)